# How do you remove a tag?

Tags: support, tags

Earlier on when I asked a question, as I am 14, I asked it in the school breaktime, but someone thought it funny to add 'porn' onto it and press post question, creating a tag called 'hackingporn' and I was wondering if it is possible to remove this tag.

Comment: If a tag is not used by any question, it will be deleted by a cleanup process which runs daily.

Answer (score 12):

Just remove the tag from the question. Tags which aren't used by any questions just disappear on their own after a short while. In this case, though, since the tag content is questionable, a staff member might come along and accelerate that process by removing the tag immediately.

Answer (score 6):

AFAIK new tags pop up in the mods' cue anyway, so it will be killed quickly. But at least now they'll know it wasn't your doing :)

Comment: I don't think we have a new tags list…but honestly if we did I'm the lazy kind of mod who would never look at it, so it wouldn't surprise me to learn we have one and I've just never seen it. :)

Comment: [It will also show up in the moderator tools new tag report.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) I guess you've just never paid attention to it. That's why we have Casey and Farhan :)